# Python import works in 2.7 but fails in 3.2+

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Importing a package with:

```
from unique_upload import unique_file_upload
```

Works in Python 2.7 but fails in Python 3.2 and above with:

```
ImportError: cannot import name unique_file_upload
```

The project structure is:

```
test/ 
   __init__.py
   test_unique_upload # <-- calling from unique_upload import unique_file_upload here

 unique_upload/ 
      __init__.py
      unique_upload
```

`unique_upload/__init__.py` contains:

```
__version__ = '0.2.0'
from unique_upload import unique_file_upload
```

Full stack trace:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_unqiue_upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/opt/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/travis/build/agconti/django-unique-upload/test/test_unqiue_upload.py", line 4, in <module>
    from unique_upload import unique_file_upload
  File "/home/travis/build/agconti/django-unique-upload/unique_upload/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from unique_upload import unique_file_upload
ImportError: cannot import name 'unique_file_upload'
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are facing one of the incompatible change of Python: [Relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html), aka PEP 328.

This should work:

```
from .unique_upload import unique_file_upload
```

Comment: `from __future__ import absolute_import`

Comment: This `from __future__ import` does the opposite of what the poster asks for: it would break the build for 2.x in the same way as it does for 3.x. Well, at least that would be consistent ;-).

Comment: I should have written that. I wanted to suggest to use your solution to make it work with 3.x and then add the future import to add back the 2.x compatibility/